# On Windows, "docker network create" got an error "hnsCall failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

And I have latest version of Docker, but when **"docker stack deploy"** *(Windows containers)* I got an error *"hnsCall failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified"*:

```
R:>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version: 18.09.2
API version: 1.39
Go version: go1.10.8
Git commit: 6247962
Built: Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version: 18.09.2
API version: 1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version: go1.10.6
Git commit: 6247962
Built: Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false
```

But *"docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml my_services"*

```
Failed creating ingress network: hnsCall failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My docker-compose.yml is fairly simple, and I can bring up individual images via "docker run".

```
version: "3"

services:
my_apps:
image: myteam/myapp:v1.0.0
deploy:
replicas: 1
resources:
limits:
cpus: "0.1"
memory: 50M
restart_policy:
condition: on-failure
ports:
- "5001:5001"
- "5003:5003"

rabbitmq:
image: myteam/rabbitmq_base:v1.0.1
deploy:
replicas: 1
resources:
limits:
cpus: "0.1"
memory: 50M
restart_policy:
condition: on-failure
ports:
- "15673:15672"
- "5673:5672"
redis:
image: myteam/redis_base:v1.0.1
deploy:
replicas: 1
resources:
limits:
cpus: "0.1"
memory: 50M
restart_policy:
condition: on-failure
ports:
- "6380:6379"
```

I digged deeper, given docker default network driver is "transparent" on Windows (Bridge on Linux), I tried manually create the networks see see what happens.

```
R:\>docker network create --driver host mynetwork
Error response from daemon: could not find plugin host in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found

R:\>docker network create --driver nat mynetwork
Error response from daemon: hnsCall failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

R:\>docker network create --driver transparent mynetwork
Error response from daemon: hnsCall failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

R:\>docker network create --driver overlay mynetwork
j94zzk3ya9w2c3xjyqog103lw
```

So, it's apparent that issue is with network creation, not docker-compose. I can't create **nat** or **transparent** network on my Windows box.

On the same box, if I switch to Linux containers, I'd have no problem creating networks.

```
R:\>docker network create --driver bridge test1
044459b2a9f0e92b29a9ce5f8c9066a31a710086a310020249ad39e24618b85a

R:\>docker network create --driver host test2
Error response from daemon: only one instance of "host" network is allowed

R:\>docker network create --driver overlay test3
gsjyz7ywwaxynj78n2r1zipee
```

**Dockers for Windows seems broken.**

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/network-drivers-topologies

Comment: Same problem here with the edge release v2.1.0.0 (36873)

Comment: Good to know i'm not alone.

Comment: I wonder whether it is related to the behavior of docker compose to create a new isolated network for each compose up to isolate the containers and provide name resolution. On Windows, only a single NAT adapter is supported (that's how the network stack works on Windows for now). If docker compose tries to create a new NAT adapter in HNS for whatever reason then it could be the issue.

Comment: There is definitively something wrong as I can only get the first `docker-compose up` to work. Any other attempt to up after that will result in the aforementioned error. After restarting my machine, I can run the up command successfully a single time before getting the error again. I am using Windows 10 Pro 1903 with Docker Desktop Edge v2.1.0.0 with experimental feature `true` on the daemon.

Comment: On same box, when i run docker-compose with linux containers no issue.

Comment: Yes same thing for me, this only impact windows networking which is based on HNS. I created another issue with simple reproduction steps and logs here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4354

Comment: Same issue here, networking on Docker for windows is utterly broken, its been this way for months.